# How to select-deselect rows in PrimeNG Datatable?

Tags: angular, primeng

I added multiple selection column and it is now able to select/ deselect rows manually in PrimeNG Datatable.

What I added:

```
<p-column [style]="{'width':'38px'}" selectionMode="multiple"></p-column>
```

I am expecting to unselect this rows after clicking a button which is in another column of data table. Is there any way to select/deselect primeNG datatable programmatically?

- Angular Version: `4.2.4`
- PrimeNG Version: `4.3.0`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can access selected rows through `selection` property:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="cars" [(selection)]="selectedRows">
```

Then when you click on the button, you just have to assign an empty array to `selectedRows`:

```
this.selectedRows = [];
```

See working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/WAWfGPa8o41g9kA9ZjyD?p=preview)

Is that what you are looking for ?